# ERROR Message: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

so i'm currently working with an oracle query that i want to grab the maximum sighting_distance along with its corresponding sighting_id value, however i keep running into the ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected error. Any ideas how to fix this error?

```
SELECT TOP 1 SIGHTING_ID, sqrt(((-28 - LATITUDE)*(-28 - LATITUDE)) + ((151 - LONGITUDE)*(151 - LONGITUDE))) AS "SIGHTING_DISTANCE" 
FROM(
    SELECT SIGHTING_ID, longitude, latitude 
    FROM SIGHTINGS)
GROUP BY SIGHTING_DISTANCE
ORDER BY ASC;
```

Comment: TOP is not Oracle

Comment: ... and `ORDER BY ASC`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that Oracle has a `TOP` keyword.  Instead, try using `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT SIGHTING_ID,
           SQRT(((-28 - LATITUDE)*(-28 - LATITUDE)) + ((151 - LONGITUDE)*(151 - LONGITUDE))) AS "SIGHTING_DISTANCE" 
    FROM SIGHTINGS
    ORDER BY "SIGHTING_DISTANCE" DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

I also fixed some other issues with your query.  You don't need to use `GROUP BY` get the max distance, and in any case you were selecting the sighting ID which is a non aggregate column.  Also, you do not need the original subquery.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT **TOP 1** does not exist in Oracle SQL. Select everything in a subquery, order the subquery, and then select everything again "where ROWMUM = 1". (There are many other ways to do this - if you have Oracle 12 there is a new feature very similar to "TOP 1".)

Comment: Thanks for that!! that solved to error but implementing the above gave me that Invalid Identifier on sighting_distance, any other tip on whats causing that?

Comment: It's because your are selecting SIGHTING_ID but your GROUP BY has SIGHTING_DISTANCE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` instead of `TOP`.